# Can I send any other parameter rather than id, to fetch Function of mongoose to get that specific data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is a fetch code, which is working fine to get the specific data from mongodb, like in the below code i got the specific year, but I wanted to send the parameter from my front end and based on that parameter I wanted to fetch, but the send parameter is not in req.body, although I get the parameter in create , update and delete functions, but not working in fetch func. I dont know why

```
export const getOfferedCourse = async(req,res) =>{ //it is time consuming task so this func is async
console.log('within controller',req.body);
    try{
       
       
        const course = await OfferedCourse.find({year:'2021'}).exec();
           
       
        res.status(200).json(course);

        
    }catch(error){
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message});

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending a POST request with JSON body, you'll need to use the [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) middleware to parse the request body into req.body

```
app.use(express.json());
```

For GET requests with query params, use [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)